# Java applet sortable list

Tags: java, jquery, applet

I'm looking for Java code, suitable for java-applet that is close to the functionality of JQuery Sortable: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Does anybody knows something suitable? (preferable free, but not strictly necessary...)

Alternatively, do you know a way to connect a Java applet JQuery...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Java Swing also has drag and drop support for nearly most of its components. You need to

```
myColorChooser.setDragEnabled(true);
```

You can read the docs here for that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/defaultsupport.html

and a demo is also available at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/basicdemo.html